# How do i automatically load code changes using docker fig

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, fig

I have a simple node program `app.js`
I mounted `app.js` file containing folder to a docker container.
When i do  `fig up` it works.
But when i change contents of `app.js`  and do  `fig stop` and `fig up` again the changes are not loaded.
How can i make sure fig reloads / rebuilds image every time i bring it up ?

I tried various combination but no luck.
how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Just mounting the volume (without actually using ADD in Dockerfile) helped me test on latest code every time i make a `fig up`

app.js
    
    `var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); 
      res.end("hello world 5");
    }).listen(3001);`

Dockerfile

`FROM cjonagam/centos-nodejs-0.10.33
RUN mkdir /home/test2
WORKDIR /home/test2
EXPOSE 3001`

`app:
  build: .
  volumes:
   - .:/home/test2
  ports:
   - "3001:3001"
  command: node app.js`

Comment: I would recommend https://github.com/b00giZm/fig-nodejs-examples/tree/master/04-express-grunt-watch is another good example with the same approach

Answer (score 1):

You need to call "fig build" to rebuild the container. I think it is easier to mount a directory on the host-system (via ADD in the dockerfile), you don't have to rebuild the container everytime then.